# How to know if stripe connect connected user onboarding processes has completed or if it requires more information?

Tags: stripe-payments

When onboarding a connected user for an Express account, they'll enter some info and be directed to the `return_url`.

But sometimes the user will reach this point without having completed all the info Stripe wanted.

What is the recommended way of knowing whether a user has/hasn't completed these onboarding requirements?

I cannot see it in the [Stripe Connect (Express Account) Onboarding docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts)

#### What I already know

Though trial and error, I can set up an account and deliberately miss vital info that Stripe wants. For this account, I see `"details_submitted": true` and `"charges_enabled": true` so those two fields don't seem to help.

#### Question

What is the recommended way for the developer to know whether a user has completed all onboarding requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to take a look at the `currently_due` [requirements](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements-currently_due) to see if there are any remaining details to collect before the account can be activated.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Do you know if it's considered okay for a connected user to accept payments before they've met all requirements? (i.e. when `currently_due` is not empty) .. Nothing errors when I attempt to pay a connected account (which has outstanding `currently_due` requirements) via credit card. But I don't want to assume if it's not okay to do it. Any idea?

Comment: A connected account can only accept payments once a base level of requirements is fulfilled. You can collect payments without meeting all requirements, but will have to complete them at some point to receive payouts.