# What Stripe Account Keys Tell Me DIFINITIVELY That a User is Fully Onboarded?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

#### Important Context

I am asking specifically about onboarding Stripe Connect **Express** account types. I don't want to allow users to accept payments directly. I will collect payments, then payout.

#### My Question

If I have a Stripe [Account](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object) object with the following keys:

```
dict_keys(['id', 'object', 'business_profile', 'capabilities',
           'charges_enabled', 'country', 'created', 'default_currency',
           'details_submitted', 'email', 'external_accounts', 'future_requirements',
           'login_links', 'metadata', 'payouts_enabled', 'requirements',
           'settings', 'tos_acceptance', 'type'])
```

will just **one** of these keys tell me definitively that an account is fully onboarded...

**OR**

is it a **combination** of keys?

#### My Question (Verbose-style)

[`details_submitted`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-details_submitted): Whether account details have been submitted. Standard accounts cannot receive payouts before this is true.

> You can check the state of the **details_submitted** parameter on their
> account to see if they’ve completed the onboarding process. ([source](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts))

> After a user is redirected to your return_url, check the state of the
> **details_submitted** parameter on their account
> ([source](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts))

[`charges_enabled`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-charges_enabled): Whether the account can create live charges.

> A user that’s redirected to your return_url might not have completed
> the onboarding process. Retrieve the user’s account and check for
> **charges_enabled**. If the account isn’t fully onboarded, provide UI
> prompts to allow the user to continue onboarding later.

[`payouts_enabled`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-payouts_enabled): Whether Stripe can send payouts to this account.

> When you receive an account.updated webhook notification or fetch an
> account via the API, you receive an Account object. The Account
> object’s **charges_enabled** and **payouts_enabled** indicate whether the
> account can create charges and accept payouts. ([source](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#determining-if-identity-or-business-verification-is-needed))

[`requirements.currently_due`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements-currently_due): Fields that need to be collected to keep the account enabled.

The idea here is that if all details have been collected, the `currently_due` array would be empty indicating they are onboarded.

```
<StripeObject at 0x2846293d5c8> JSON: {
  "alternatives": [],
  "current_deadline": null,
  "currently_due": [],
  "disabled_reason": null,
  "errors": [],
  "eventually_due": [
    "person_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.dob.day",
    "person_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.dob.month",
    "person_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.dob.year",
    "person_aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.ssn_last_4"
  ],
  "past_due": [],
  "pending_verification": []
}
```

### Again, My Question

So is just checking for `details_submitted` enough to verify if someone is fully onboarded? Or is it a combination of the above like `details_submitted` AND `requirements['currently_due']` AND ... you get the point.

Links to proof / evidence would be more helpful than general opinion answers.

**Similar Questions**

- [How can I tell through the Stripe API if a connected account is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036019/how-can-i-tell-through-the-stripe-api-if-a-connected-account-is-complete) - question specific to **Standard** account types.
- [How to know if stripe connect connected user onboarding processes has completed or if it requires more information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590218/how-to-know-if-stripe-connect-connected-user-onboarding-processes-has-completed) - not sure I believe this answer as I haven't seen this mentioned in the primary Stripe documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onboarding happens incrementally (e.g. verification requirements will change over time if they are not collected up front), so the short answer is: there isn't one single property you can look at to tell if and account is fully onboarded.

[You'll want to check the `currently_due` and `eventually_due` properties on the Account object](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#determining-if-identity-or-business-verification-is-needed) in order to discern if an account is on a path to being fully-onboarded. Once verification requirements are met, they are generally considered 'fully onboarded'.

From the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#determining-if-identity-or-business-verification-is-needed):

> The Account object has a requirements hash, representing the
> requirements needed to verify the account. The requirements hash has
> the following arrays:
>
> - eventually_due: Information in this array isn’t needed immediately,    but it will be when certain thresholds are hit. All required
>   information starts in this array.
> - currently_due: Information in this array needs to be collected by the    current_deadline and is a subset of eventually_due.
> - past_due: Information in this array means the account is disabled    because the required information wasn’t collected. past_due is a
>   subset of currently_due.

Here's also a good resource for country-specific onboarding requirements: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/required-verification-information

Comment: [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide) says "You can check the state of the `details_submitted` parameter on their account to see if they’ve completed the onboarding process." Your answer suggests relying on the `requirements` object. So you're saying `details_submitted` doesn't tell you if an account has completed the onboarding process. Stripe's documentation seems to contradict itself. How is `details_submitted` even resolved to True or False? What is the logic behind it? Do you happen to know?

Comment: Further, does `details_submitted` change from True to False if later-on thresholds are hit triggering some `eventually_due` requisites?

Comment: Once all `currently_due` requirements on the account have been met, then `details_submitted` will be `true`. But, if the account has unresolved `eventually_due` requirements, then Stripe requests additional verification details at some point in the future. When that happens, then `eventually_due` requirements will turn into `currently_due` requirements and the `details_submitted` bool will go back to `false`.

Comment: I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695888/how-does-stripes-details-submitted-resolve-to-true-or-false). karllekko said: "It just means the user completed the initial onboarding. It never gets set back to false if something else is required later." Not sure who is right but I have a somewhat general directional idea now.