# How Does Stripe's "details_submitted" Resolve to True or False?

Tags: stripe-payments

What code logic does Stripe use to determine if a Stripe Account's `details_submitted` boolean returns True or False?

```
>>> import stripe
>>> stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
>>> acct = stripe.Account.retrieve("acct_13kKlFJld93FKx")
>>> acct.details_submitted
False
```

Is the logic made public somewhere?

Stripe says "You can check the state of the `details_submitted` parameter on their account to see if they’ve completed the onboarding process." But Stripe's documentation seems to contradict itself because an account can later require more information if thresholds are hit that trigger some `requirements.eventually_due` requisites.

If new requisites become needed, does `details_submitted` change from True to False?

The code logic would tell me all this which is why I'm asking.

Comment: It just means the user completed the initial onboarding. It never gets set back to false if something else is required later.

Comment: @karllekko how can I verify that?

Comment: You could contact Stripe's support I would imagine!

Comment: Pass. Every time I have contacted Stripe support, they send me into an endless loop of "initial" questions rather than ever trying to answer. Hence, I have turned to StackOverflow due to the lack of support (multiple occasions now).

Answer (score 0):

> If new requisites become needed, does details_submitted change from True to False?

No, it does not. New requisites might become needed, so `payouts_enabled` will change to `False`. But once an account is initialized `details_submitted` will stay `True`.